# How to play a YouTube video with HTML 5's <video>

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video

I can I play a YouTube video in my site using HTML 5 `<video>` controls?

I am able to run the video for MP4, ogg format,

```
<video width="710" height="423" controls>
    <source src="testvideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

but how to run teh video where the source is from youtube
ex:

```
<video width="710" height="423" controls>
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/v/<youtube video id>?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&fs=1" type="????"></source>
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I provided the valid source and given type as `video/youtube`, but got the error as `No video with supported format and MIME type found`

Please let me know if you anybody have any input

Thanks, Sharath

Answer (score 0):

if your tag

```
<youtube video id>
```

produces the 11 character code such as for this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2ByLmLnYJ8

the 11 character code  would be  t2ByLmLnYJ8

then I think you should try

```
<iframe width="710" height="423" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<youtube video id>">
</iframe>
```

It is my understanding that YouTube has taken over ensuring that the video format is compatible with the device so you don't have to worry about it with this method.